# Is it clear that $y^3=f(x)$ has bad reduction at $3$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-curves

Bad reduction is defined as 'nonexistence' of a model where the curve has good reduction. So let's take the curve $C$ which is affinely given by
$$y^3 = f(x)$$
(absolutely irred, $f$ no multiple roots).

Is it clear that $C$ has bad reduction at $p=3$? And why?

Some smart person might in the end find a model where $C$ has good reduction at $p=3$.

Comment: What about $y^3=x$?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi.  The problem is $y^3= x^2+a^3$.  This curve is singular in characteristic $3$ at $(x,y)=(0,a)$.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi: You may also assume $\deg(f)\geq 4$ to avoid trivial cases

Comment: What kind of base Dedekind scheme are you working over?  Based on my computations, there seems to be a big difference between the case when the residue field is perfect (contains cube roots) and the case where it is not perfect.  Are you allowing a base change with purely inseparable extension of residue fields?

Comment: Let's just work over $\mathbb Q$, for simplicity. Then a naive model of $C$ is given by the equation above. Then the special fiber (over $\mathbb F_3$) is singular by the Jacobian criterion. But I don't get to the point where $C$ has bad reduction at $p=3$.

Comment: If your flat curve with smooth generic fiber is defined over an open subset of $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ that contains the prime $3$, assuming that the ideal $\langle 3, f(x),f'(x) \rangle \subset \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is the unit ideal (i.e., no common zeroes of $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ in characteristic $3$), then it appears that a "regular blowup" of $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/\langle y^3-f(x)\rangle)$ at the reduced closed points of the reduction mod $3$ that are singular gives a desingularization with smooth reduction mod $3$.  This changes if the residue field is imperfect.

Comment: So let's say $\deg f \geq 4$, then I'd have at least two common zeroes. Does $C$ have bad reduction at $3$ then?

Comment: "So let's say $\text{deg}\ f \geq 4$, then I'd have at least two common zeroes."  I am afraid that I do not understand.  Are you asking what happens when there are common zeroes of $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ after reducing modulo $3$?